# Int64 parsing from args in Frida-trace for iOS binaries

Tags: ios, hopper, frida

I'm using frida-trace to log some methods and I've come across the following.

```
 onEnter(log, args, state) {
    log(`-[Somefunction somefield64:${args[2]}]`)
 }
```

`somefield64` returns what I believe to be an int64 like `0x81008d000101e7`.

I'm not sure how to see the value behind this, all read methods (readU64/S64) complain it's not a valid address (access violation), so I assume I need to change the format.

Looking at the method in a disassembler and its references show it just takes a string like

```
extern _some_field_constant
```

with the call as

```
[Somefunction somefield64:**_some_field_constant]
```

So I know how to get to the constant with

```
Module.getExportByName('SomeModule',"_some_field_constant")
```

And I can see the address.

I'm just not seeing the reference to how to retrieve the field from `args[2]` via frida-trace.

I had a similar method with similar functionality (no int64) returned a `__NSCFConstantString` and just managed to do

```
onEnter(log, args, state) {
    log(`-[SomeOther someField:${args[2]}]`);
    log(ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithString_(args[2]))                                                                                           
}
```

What do I need to do (or read in terms of technical documentation, excuse my incomplete understanding/explanation for experienced reverse engineering folks out there) to parse the int64 into a `NativePointer` so I can get the address in memory.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured it out. The similar method was just super easier it seemed to be the same but it wasn't at all   had to follow the internal assembly which pointed to a function via br x4 and loads another function from another framework the int64 field matches some conditionals there, so it seems I never was meant to parse it?  . Thank you again and please vote to close this question as I am satisfied :)

Comment: If you found the answer, please post it below so others can benefit.